# 3 mirrored volumne in window 7

Tags: windows-7, software-raid, raid-1, mirroring

Can I make 3 mirrored Hard disk in window 7? I would like to use backup system(mirrored volume) with RAID 1 in window7. But the problem is that I can make two volume mirrored. Is that possible?

Comment: if you use hardware RAID and select RAID1E then this should work, but I cannot find this in the build-in software. (Note that windows software RAID and the OS disks might be *interesting* if the wrong disk fails, so try to only mirror the data volumes).

Comment: I would like to use software RAID. Windows 7 supports it as built in. But I can't find three hard disk mirrored on window 7.

Comment: wouldn't it be better if one of them was not mirrored?  that it was a backup of the data , an ability to recover if the hardware goes bad, but also not mirroring every error problem malware and virus too?  A good 3rd might be a disk that is set aside that has 90% of everything on it, but isnt presentally connected.  One possible way to do that is to mirror, then break that mirror and create a different mirror (but again a disconnected not spun-up drive is a real backup).